# d3.js How to add mouseover function when it already had brush and zoom function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I had this code http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172 a reference. It has brush and zoom function

But also I would like to have mouseover function to show the value and time. But it seems that the zoom function already cover the upper margin.

Is there any method to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the clip area, (of the upper, aka focus chart).

Refer to this: http://wrobstory.github.io/2013/11/D3-brush-and-tooltip.html